# How to set shell environment variable from autotools .am file?

Tags: shell, make, variable, autotools

I need to get the shell equivalent of

export PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0

to work in an autotools .am file, but can't get it working.  I currently have this declaration in my Makefile.am file:

PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0

but when the build runs it is not behaving as though that variable is set as an environment variable.  Can anyone advise on what the correct syntax is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To declare environment variables is better to user the configure.ac file. There you can write:

`export PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0`

However, I am not sure what are you trying to achieve with that. Do you need an environmental variable to run your program or to compile it? In the former case, other methods are preferable.

Comment: This variable only needed for the build, trying your suggestion now.

Comment: If you need it for building the project, `configure.ac` is the right place :)